# asp.net "fbclid error" with Server Error in '/' Application

Tags: asp.net, facebook

Facebook now adds fbclid query string to URLs since October. But after this an error occured when ppl click our ads at facebook:

http://ifwedding.izfas.com.tr/10gelinlik-tasarim-yarismasi?fbclid=IwAR22Pu_tkT6KLsQr6oWboS6uJbiDlt0lRiK8MKaXxzjW6CZ_63aXptlEwZw

Saying : Runtime Error
Description: An exception occurred while processing your request. Additionally, another exception occurred while executing the custom error page for the first exception. The request has been terminated.

What should I do for this error? 
Thanks for all replies.

Comment: you have to fix this on your server, just google for the error. for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17274481/an-exception-occurred-while-processing-your-request-additionally-another-exce

Comment: I did it! Now, giving  Error Code    0x800700b7
When I search at support.microsoft, it says delete duplicated 
<add accessType="Allow" users="*" />
But there is one user allowed at my page.

Comment: you should turn that into an answer and accept it